# How to use Join in select statement using linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

Hi Have a two tables that have a relationship like below ..

```
class Boothtable
{
  public int BoothId {get;set;}
  public string BoothName {get;set;}
  public double Price {get;set;}
  public int RoomId{get;set;}
} 

class RoomTable
{
   public int RoomId {get;set;}
   public string RoomName{get;set;}
   public sting Location {get;set;}

}
```

I am trying to write a join query using LINQ to join the the boothtable to the roomstable on RoomId and return all properties from the boothtable and only return the RoomName property from the Rooms table. is there anyone that can direct me how to achieve this?

So far i have a linq exp like this but it only returns all properties from the booths table.

```
var getData = from boothtable in context.Boothtable
              join roomtable in context.RoomTable 
              on boothtable.RoomId equals roomtable.RoomId
              where boothtable.BoothId == someId
              select boothtable;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to retrieve properties from both you must project an object containing data from both. This uses an anonymous object to do so:

```
select new { boothtable, roomtable }
```

If you want to return this collection of anonymous objects from a method then define a custom object with the two properties and instantiate it

```
select new YourCustomObjet { Booth = boothtable, Room = roomtable }
```

If you only want some of the properties (missed it at first) then as you project the objects in the examples above just project the specific fields:

```
select new 
{
    boothtable.BoothId,
    boothtable.BoothName,
    boothtable.Price,
    roomtable.RoomName 
}
```

*Notice that if it is an anonymous object and the desired property names are the same, no need to explicitly define a name*

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Try this -

```
var getData = (from boothtable in context.Boothtable
              join roomtable in context.RoomTable 
              on boothtable.RoomId equals roomtable.RoomId
              where boothtable.BoothId == someId
              select new 
              {
                  BoothId = boothtable.BoothId,
                  BoothName = boothtable.BoothName,
                  Price = boothtable.Price,
                  RoomName = roomtable.RoomName 
              });
```